# Ms access VBA - Select Case with MsgBox from module function

Tags: vba, function, ms-access, select, msgbox

Since one often uses one and the same message (i.e. error notes) on several forms in MS access, I thought about organizing all messages inside a table and call these with a public function:

```
Public Function message(msg_name As String, Optional msg_type As VbMsgBoxStyle)

output =   MsgBox DLookup("Msg_Text", "vba_msg", "Msg_Name='" & msg_name & "'"), _
           msg_type, _
           DLookup("Msg_Caption", "vba_msg", "Msg_Name='" & msg_name & "'")
```

Plain and simple. Nicely working for simple notifications ("ouput = " and parentheses wouldn't be necessary for this, of course). However, I can't use these messages in a Select Case context:

```
Select Case message("test_message_name", vbYesNo)
  Case vbYes
    MsgBox "Yes"
  Case vbNo
    MsgBox "No"
End Select
```

Neither pressing "Yes" nor "No" are recognized as such. I only get a response if I define "Case Else" as well.
If I do the same procedure within one an the same Sub, everything works fine:

```
output =   MsgBox DLookup("Msg_Text", "vba_msg", "Msg_Name='" & "test_message_name" & "'"), _
           msg_type, _
           DLookup("Msg_Caption", "vba_msg", "Msg_Name='" & "test_message_name" & "'")

Select Case output
  Case vbYes
    MsgBox "Yes"
  Case vbNo
    MsgBox "No"
End Select
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, almost forgot, you're also being a little inconsistent in naming: `Optional ms_type` is `msg_type` later, and `output` is never declared. Try turning on `Option Explicit` to spot these errors more easily (you will get compile errors for both of them with it on).

Comment: Ah, thanks. The "ms_type" was actually a typo. I didn't copy-paste from Access but wrote the code down again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just forgotten to both assign the function return parameter type, and to assign `output` to the function.

`Public Function message(msg_name As String, Optional ms_type As VbMsgBoxStyle) As MsgBoxResult`

And

`message = output`

or just

```
message =  MsgBox DLookup("Msg_Text", "vba_msg", "Msg_Name='" & msg_name & "'"), _
           msg_type, _
           DLookup("Msg_Caption", "vba_msg", "Msg_Name='" & msg_name & "'")
```